# Ruby: Active Record: Boolean accept value , why 'y' and 'yes' cannot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails model using rails 4.1, which one field is boolean type. I want to change the boolean value using 'y', or 'yes' but it doesn't work. it only allow 't', 'on', true.
my database is postrgresql

```
2.1.1 :031 > a.default_indicator = 'y'
 => "y"
2.1.1 :032 > a.default_indicator
 => false
2.1.1 :033 > a.default_indicator = 'yes'
 => "yes"
2.1.1 :034 > a.default_indicator
 => false
2.1.1 :035 > a.default_indicator = 'true'
 => "true"
```

Any one knows why?

Comment: What happens if you do `a.default_indicator = 'y'; a.save; a.reload; a.default_indicator`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find some constants in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column` that are used when Rails needs to typecast values from database fields into model attributes:

```
TRUE_VALUES = [true, 1, '1', 't', 'T', 'true', 'TRUE', 'on', 'ON'].to_set
FALSE_VALUES = [false, 0, '0', 'f', 'F', 'false', 'FALSE', 'off', 'OFF'].to_set

# convert something to a boolean
def value_to_boolean(value)
  if value.is_a?(String) && value.blank?
    nil
  else
    TRUE_VALUES.include?(value)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this in your Model as method & save it DB accordingly.

For Eg.

```
class MyEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active
     return false unless active=='y'|| active == 'yes'
     true
  end
end
```

The above method will return True or false.You can save your data from this method.

Comment: The strange thing is that postgreSQL should support 'y' and 'yes' based on its document. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-boolean.html

Comment: just because PostgreSQL supports it, doesn't mean all other databases (which ActiveRecord also supports) do.

Comment: He said in the OP he using postgres though.